# How to add method annotation for a class created with PHP's Soap Client

Tags: php, annotations, soap-client

I use PhpStorm as my PHP IDE. It has a feature where it will issue a warning if it detects you using a non-existent method to a class. Usually it is a typo, but it could also be a method not yet created.

In cases where it does not detect a valid class, one can manually hint the IDE with an annotation similar to this.

```
/** @var MyClass $myClass **/
```

This would force the IDE to allow the variable $myClass-> to detect all available methods of MyClass.

I have come across a problem where I have a class that is being generated dynamically from a call to a third party SOAP service. PhpStorm is flagging a method call to this new class because the method I am calling is not part of the SoapClient class.

These are the two lines of code I am working with for this question. The warning comes on the second line, *SendCharFax not found in \SoapClient*

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://ws.interfax.net/dfs.asmx?wsdl");
$result = $client->SendCharFax($params);
```

I understand clearly why the IDE warning shows, but I want to know how I can eliminate the warning. I have spent a good deal of time searching SO and the Internet, and I cannot find any information to help me wth this problem.

How can I eliminate this IDE warning?

Comment: How about trying something like this that will generate php classes from the wsdl https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I will look this over!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want full auto completion and dynamic variable hint, use a WSDL to php generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.